# Where to include js files ,in actions(controller) or view (zf2)?

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

Hi all im working on zf2, I was allways including js files from the view pages. But i can include it in the controller also using appendscript(). Which is the best method according to mvc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript works with view output - the view knows, what javascript is needed to make everything work. And the view might not be directed to the browser, other view media might be used. For this reason, I prefere adding javascript from inside view.

Comment: which is the best method according to the mvc? any idea?